# Sideload Excel Add-in on Mac

Tags: excel, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm trying to sideload an Excel Add-in using this method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/sideload-an-office-add-in-on-ipad-and-mac but the file just doesn't appear in **My Add-ins**

(My mac and excel follow the prerequisites and I already tested the addin on windows and it works perfectly)

I've looked everywhere for other tips or solutions but couldn't find anything.  Help please !